# Probability there is a substring that has the same number of 1s and 0s.

Tags: probability

If you have a random binary string of length $2n$. What is the probability that there is a substring of length $n$ that has the same number of $1$s and $0$s? We can assume $n$ is even.

For one substring this is just ${n \choose n/2} 1/2^{n}$.

I can see you can apply http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality to get an upper bound of ${n \choose n/2} n/2^{n}$ but can you do any better?  This upper bound is at least $1$ for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Note: This is not at all a duplicate of the earlier question that uses much the same language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a substring of length $n$ with such property to exist,

the number of $0$'s and the number of $1$'s in the original string should both be at least $n/2$.

Let us consider the compliment: if we have the number of $0$'s less than $n/2$, then we cannot find such substring.

Thus, probability of the compliment is 
$$
2\sum_{0\leq k < n/2} \binom{2n}{k}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$

Here, $2$ is multiplied because we also have to consider when the number of $1$'s less than $n/2$.

Hence, the probability that you are looking for is 
$$1-2\sum_{0\leq k < n/2} \binom{2n}{k}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$

Note: This probability converges to $1$ by Central Limit Theorem.